# RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

`RecyclerView.Adapter` отрисовывает только одну запись, хотя в списке их больше, отрисовывывает только первую, под дебагом смотрел - выходит после отрисовки первой записи. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема

```
public class TripAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TripAdapter.TripViewHolder> {

public List<Refueling> refueling;
public TripAdapter(List<Refueling> refueling) {
    this.refueling = refueling;
}

@Override
public TripViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new TripViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.page_refueling, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TripViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.price.setText("Заправил на:" + refueling.get(position).price.toString());
    holder.priceFuel.setText("Цена : " + refueling.get(position).price_fuel.toString());
    holder.fuel.setText("Заправил (л): " + String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(refueling.get(position).fuel_l)));
    holder.distance.setText("Проехал (км): " + refueling.get(position).distance.toString());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return refueling.size();
}

public class TripViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView priceFuel;
    private TextView fuel;
    private TextView price;
    private TextView distance;

    public TripViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        priceFuel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_fuel_rv);
        fuel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fuel_rv);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_rv);
        distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance_rv);
    }
}
```

}

```
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(new TripAdapter(Refueling.refuelings));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где конструктор и как вообще данные попадают в адаптер?

Comment: В адаптере нет конструктора и переданного через этот конструктор набора данных, которые можно итерировать. То, что у вас там какой то внешний класс с данными адаптеру совсем не интересно.

Comment: Добавил конструктор, адаптер данные видит, но рисует только первую запись

Comment: Я рискну предположить ( у меня были такие грабли) что у вас ваш item высоту имеет match_parent. Попробуйте прокрутить ваш список. Посмотрите я прав или нет

Comment: Да...вы правы...это печально))Спасибо